# Android studio module

Tags: java, android, layout, gradle

In my project I've got main package and second one is module **`(app2)`**. As module I use standard application -> import to project  -> change it as library and make dependencies **`(compile project(':app2')).`**

Everything is ok but when I compile, it auto start on module (app2). How to make auto start main app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run --> Edit Configuration --> Select app module

Comment: by this way i can force to run main app. Is it ok to import and use as module standard project which isn't library?